# Add syntax highlighting for [gdscript] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[Godot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godot_(game_engine)) is becoming increasingly popular as a choice for a game engine, and it's also becoming popular in Stack Overflow as well: [gdscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdscript), [godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godot)

It also has support with [Highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) as well, and I think that (if highlighting for it isn't in the site already), it should also be set as the default for the [gdscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdscript).

Comment: This would need to be a request for gdscript highlighting to be deployed on the network and not just adding syntax highlighting to the tags. While gdscript syntax highlighting _is_ supported by hljs (via [highlightjs-gdscript](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlightjs-gdscript)) it is _not_ in [our supported subset of langauges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857). A developer would have to deploy the hljs support before a moderator would be able to set syntax highlighting for the tags.

Comment: You might have better luck on requesting the network-wide deployment on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but please note [\[w\]hile it's fine to request for the SE team to add additional supported languages, these requests are extremely likely to be considered low-priority and as such deferred.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)

Comment: Re *"Highlight.js"*: AKA *The Weird Syntax Highlighter*